# HTML5 audio and video players fixed to bottom right of page (picture in picture like)

Tags: html, audio, video, mediaelement.js

I am building an application with **HTML5 audio** and **video** players.
I try to improve user experience adding an option where a video can still be played at the bottom right of the page (fixed) when user scroll down the page (sort of picture in picture but only for the current page).

I tried to use the jQuery `clone()` method but the fixed one did not have synchronised commands (play, pause, ...) with the original one.

On my researches, I couldn't find any jQuery plugins or tutorials to do that so does someone knows a trails I should follow ?

Thanks for your help !

**My project**:

- MediaElement.js 2.18.0

**Edit**:

Extract of my `<audio>` code: (`<audio>` and `<video>` are handled by `mediaelement.js`)

```
<audio class="mediaelement" data-autoplay="false">
  <source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Comment: you need to post your code

Comment: I edited my question to add extract of my <audio> tag. That's the only code I got as I start from nothing (it's the goal of my question). I deleted my borky tests (clone) as it was not a good way to make it to work. Thanks !